# Find the sum : $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{2^i}{1+x^{2^{i}}}$

Tags: summation

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{2^i}{1+x^{2^{i}}}$

What technique is applicable here? I can't find a way to manipulate this sum to make it telescope. Just guide me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\frac{2^{i+1}}{1-x^{2^{i+1}}}  = \frac{2^{i+1}}{(1-x^{2^i})(1+x^{2^i})} = 2^i \left ( \frac1{1-x^{2^i}} + \frac1{1+x^{2^i}}\right )$$

Therefore

$$\frac{2^i}{1+x^{2^i}} = \frac{2^{i+1}}{1-x^{2^{i+1}}} - \frac{2^i}{1-x^{2^i}}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: @AdityaParson: the trick is knowing that $$x^{2^{i+1}} = (x^2)^i$$  Then you somehow just know to exploit the fact that $$1+y = \frac{1-y^2}{1-y}$$

Comment: Nicely done. Can you give me some insight into your motivation to this approach? Please

Comment: @RonGordon Huh?  $x^{2^{i+1}} = (x^{2^i})^2$, as you have used above.

Comment: @SpamIAm: Thanks for catching the typo.  I meant $$x^{2^{i+1}} = (x^2)^{2^i}$$