# Find the value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n}}{x^{2^n}+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the value of $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n}}{x^{2^n}+1}$$

I recently came across a question in which we had to find the value of the above question. The question seemed simple at first glance but the term $2^n$ in the numerator is posing me with a problem. I could neither reduce it to a telescopic series nor could I compare it with any standard expansion. I've run out of ideas. Would someone please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is my editing correct? " but the term $n^2$ in the numerator" Do you mean $2^n$?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the Sum of the Series: $1/(x+1) + 2/(x^2 + 1) + 4/(x^4 +1) +\cdots$ $n$ terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995305/find-the-sum-of-the-series-1-x1-2-x2-1-4-x4-1-cdots-n-ter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Multiply by $x^{2^n}-1$ in the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Thank you Shashwat1337

Answer (score 4):

The series **is** telescopic: note that
$$\frac{2^{n}}{x^{2^n}+1}=\dfrac{2^n}{x^{2^{n}}-1} - \dfrac{2^{n+1}}{x^{2^{n+1}}-1}.$$